# Performing aggregate operations on two JSON-like data

Tags: data-structures

My application periodically consumes data from an API:

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "val": 12
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "val": 22
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "val": 32
    }
]
```

Its task is to perform some operations on this data, for example, to subtract the "A" value from its previous sample. So we always keep the current sample for further use.

The incoming data has two constraints:

1. In some iterations some parts of data may be missing, i.e. the "A" object may not be available in some JSONs,
2. The order of objects is not guaranteed to be consistent, i.e. in a JSON we may have A, B, C, and in another one, we may have "C", "A", "B" ...

The intuitive way to perform these operations is a linear search. We loop through the current JSON and for each object we search for the counterpart in the previous JSON. Then we perform the calculations and put them inside another JSON.

What is an efficient way to do this task? I preferably like to do this in Go but the language is not important.

Comment: From my perspective the best solution would be to find an already built library that does this efficiently and use that rather than reinvent it. Storage mechanism, volume, and throughput/latency may also have some bearing. Do you get 1 a day, 100 a day, 1 million a day? Do you store it somewhere? The "preceding value of A" must be stored somewhere

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Since each JSON array has at most 700 objects, I can keep it in memory.  By the way, I will need persistence too, currently, I am using MySQL but I am thinking about using a NoSQL solution such as MongoDB. I have about 120 incoming JSON each day.

Comment: I haven't used NoSQL but my understanding is that this would probably be the easiest method. Ingest all your data as it arrives then just run required queries on it, including queries that look for the prior value of A. Because for example if the prior value of A was a week ago, you don't want to have to keep a week of JSON in memory, in fact you may not know how long you need to keep the data in memory

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually if the data was not available in any iteration, we would simply ignore it. I mean only the two consecutive data with 2 minutes time difference is important.

Comment: OK that sounds like more of a streaming use case. This is the first thing that came up when I googled. I have no idea if that's the "best" though. https://tibcosoftware.github.io/flogo/labs/streams-aggregate/